# Visual Basic Decimal Calculations Result in Double

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Basic and I'm doing some calculations with Decimals, however Visual Studio throws this error on each calculation: "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Double' to 'Decimal'". I understand the meaning of this error. I'm just wondering why the answer would be a Double in the first place. Here's the code (the line producing the error is the one which reads FWT = 0.1 * (taxable - 116)):

```
Private Function GetFWT(ByVal allowances As Integer, ByVal status As String, ByVal gross As Decimal) As Decimal

    Dim FWT As Decimal
    Dim taxable As Decimal

    taxable = gross - CDec(allowances * 70.19)

    If status = "S" Then
        If taxable < 116 Then
            FWT = 0
        ElseIf taxable >= 116 And taxable < 200 Then
            FWT = 0.1 * (taxable - 116)
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

I've cut out the other ElseIf statements as they're all similar and there's quite a few. Visual Studio recommends using CDec() to solve the error, so I'll implement that to solve it (unless anyone knows a better solution), but I'm just trying to understand why a calculation with Decimal variables and literal numbers would yield a Double.

Comment: So for `= 0.1 * (taxable - 116)` what datatype do you think that the  literal `0.1` is?

Comment: Based on the answer below, I understand now that the literal is interpreted as a Double, so I see now where the Double is coming from. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `0.1` as a `Decimal` or `Double`?

My understanding is that literals would be interpreted as a Double, and this will yield a `Double` result.

You could try: `FWT = 0.1D * (taxable-116)`

Comment: I did not know that literals are Doubles by default. Thank you!

Comment: @SamanthaMaurice neither did I, until I looked it up :)  Makes perfect sense though, since Double type is used much more frequently and requires less memory to store.